# Xampp Mysql installation

Tags: mysql, xampp

I had MySql installed on my computer(OS: Ubuntu 10.04) and today I installed XAMPP.
The PHP and Perl are installed correct but the Mysql database in deactivated.
Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict between these 2 installation of MySQL. Is it possible to remove the first one and test MySQL in Xampp again ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to be more clear on what you mean by deactivated? I assume you mean it is not starting?

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP has MySQL; maybe the old MySQL and the new MySQL use the same port number. so some instance don't start